# Office add-in using bootstrap token to get other tokens

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have a requirement to call other APIs other than graph(like Dynamics, Power Automate etc.,) from our Add-in. All examples in [Office Add-in Samples](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples) suggest to use bootstrap token and then exchange it to get tokens for subsequent APIs and make calls on the server. This forces all communication from our Add-in to be proxied via our server. This can be a unncessary performance bottle-neck. Can we not send the OBO tokens back to our client side Add-in and call other services directly from the client? Is there a known security issue with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The "received wisdom" about whether access tokens should be sent to clients or stored on clients has fluctuated over the last 10 -15 years, but in recent years the pendulum has swung pretty decisively to the idea that access tokens should not be on the clients. Client-to-server communication is much more vulnerable than server-to-server communication, because there are a wide variety of well-known ways to attack clients and trick users. At the same time, bad actors don't know when server-to-server communication is going to take place and it is much harder to get access to the server computers on either end of the communication.

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/blob/main/Samples/auth/Outlook-Add-in-SSO/AttachmentDemoWeb/Controllers/AzureADAuthController.cs @Rick - example from office samples provide an example for returning token to the client in case of SSO failure. You think this is a security issue?

Comment: Yes. And that sample is in the process of being changed to fix that issue.

Comment: Passing the token back to the client is a security issue because it could be intercepted or leaked. We have this information documented online: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#pass-the-access-token-to-server-side-code

Comment: Thanks @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT and Rick. In cases when we don’t get bootstrap token (SSO failure exception flow), the recommendation is to get a token for our WebAPI using MSAL (PKCE flow) on the client and then pass this token to our server and use OBO token flow for interaction with other services?

Comment: If you are using MSAL on the client, you can directly request the resource token you need without going through OBO.